# How to configure two Epson scanners on my PC (18.04)

Tags: configuration, scanner, epson, etc

I want to configure a second epson scanner device on my PC.
Does anybody know the format of required lines in imagescan.conf (epson scanner interface configuration - V3)?

My first scanner, a Epson Workforce Pro WF-3725 works fine, connected via wlan with a fix IP adress, configured in imagescan.conf.
Now I want to add a second scanner, a Epson Stylus Office BX635 FWD, but cannot find documentation how to add it to the configuration file.
At the moment, calling the imagescan program, I have no possibility to select the scanner.
A selection of scanners is documented in epson imagescan program documentation ... but configuration example there is poor ... and I cannot get any information from Epson service ...

There must exist a possibility to configure more than one scanners.
I prefer to connect the second scanner via wlan ...
... but I would accept a temporary usb cable connection also.
(This would be my fallback, if my wlan-router is out of service.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the required information in source package files:

/etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf:

{

...

[devices]

net.udi    = esci:networkscan://192.168.0.208:1865
net.vendor = Epson
net.model  = WF-3725
net.name   = Epson WF-3725 Wlan

net2.udi    = esci:networkscan://192.168.0.209:1865
net2.vendor = Epson
net2.model  = BX635FWD
net2.name   = Epson BX 635 FWD Wlan

}